# Append string to a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with a numpy array called "C_ClfGtLabels" in which 374 artist/creator names are stored. I want to append a 375th artist class with a string "other artists". I thought I could just do that as follows:

```
C_ClfGtLabels.append('other artists')
```

However, this results in the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

I saw found this problem a few times on stackoverflow, to which the answer in one case was to use concatenate instead of append. When I tried that I got the following error:

> TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to int

It seems to be a problem that the datatype does not match the datatype that I, trying to append/concatenate, which would be of type string. However, I don't know what I should do to make them match. The data inside the Clabels array is as follows:

```
    [u"admiral, jan l'" u'aldegrever, heinrich' u'allard, abraham'
 u'allard, carel' u'almeloveen, jan van' u'altdorfer, albrecht'
 u'andriessen, jurriaan' u'anthonisz., cornelis' u'asser, eduard isaac' ..]
```

Any advice on how I can setup the "other artists" string so that I can append it to C_ClfGtLabels?

Comment: what is the shape and the dtype of your `C_ClfGtLabels` numpy array? what do you mean by `C_ClfGtLabels.np.append('other artists')`?

Comment: The shape of the array is (374,), the dtype seems to be unsigned int (.dtype returns <u58).

Oops, I meant C_ClfGtLabels.append instead of C_ClfGtLabels.np.append. I just want to append the string "other artists" to the array.

Comment: what is the output of `C_ClfGtLabels.np`?

Comment: you could probably work on a list instead: `lst = list(C_ClfGtLabels)` if you really need, you can always convert it back later `np.asarray(lst)`

Comment: The .np was a mistake, ignore that (I just removed it from my question). The output of the C_ClfGtlabels is as displayed in the last block of the question. Still, to answer your question, the output of C_ClfGtLabels.np is " 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'np' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick workaround is to convert your `C_ClfGtLabels` into a list first, append, and convert it back into an `ndarray`

```
lst = list(C_ClfGtLabels)
lst.append('other artists')

C_ClfGtLabels = np.asarray(lst)
```